# Using Parentheses in Partial Template Specialization

Tags: c++

In code below what is the difference between `<Result (Arg0, Arg1)>` and `<Result, Arg0, Arg1>`

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

template <typename Result, typename Arg0 = void, typename Arg1 = void>
class Signal;

template <typename Result, typename Arg0, typename Arg1>
class Signal<Result (Arg0, Arg1)> // is this the same as <Result, Arg0, Arg1>
{
  Result test(Arg0 arg0, Arg1 arg1)
  {

  }
};

int main()
{
  Signal<void (int, int)> s; // or Signal<void, int, int>?  
}
```

Comment: I believe the former denotes (1) function signature whereas the latter denotes (3) types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Result(Arg0, Arg1)` is a single type. It is read "function taking `Arg0` and `Arg1` returning `Result`". When you specialize `Signal`,

```
template <typename Result, typename Arg0, typename Arg1>
class Signal<Result(Arg0, Arg1)>
```

you've only given 1 argument, but it takes 3. The other 2 become the defaults, as stated in the template declaration. Thus, this is the same as

```
template <typename Result, typename Arg0, typename Arg1>
class Signal<Result(Arg0, Arg1), void, void>
```

Note that it makes absolutely no difference that the name of the parameters in the specialization match up with the declaration. The `Arg0` in the specialization is different from the `Arg0` in the declaration. In the specialization, `Arg0`-from-the-declaration is not specified, which is why it defaults to `void`. Similarly, in the declaration

```
Signal<void(int, int)> s;
```

you've really written

```
Signal<void(int, int), void, void> s;
```

I doubt you meant to do either of these things. Just use commas.

Comment: `Signal<void(int, int), int, int> s;` does not compile, why? and how `Arg0, Arg1` from the `Result` definition maps to `test` function arguments?

Answer (score 4):

The difference between `<Result (Arg0, Arg1)>` and `<Result, Arg0, Arg1>` is the the former is a single type (that of a function), with nested types in it, while the latter if 3 separate types.

Functions in C++ has a type.  Without getting into everything that is part of the type generally it will be

```
return_type(paramter_type1, paramter_type1, ..., paramter_typeN)
```

So, for a function like `int foo(double, char)`, its type is `int(double, char)`.  What your specialization does is allow you to pass a function type to the template and it will deduce the parameters from that, instead of having you specify them yourself. That would look like

```
int foo(double, char);
Signal<decltype(foo)> s;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't the same. This:

```
Result (Arg0, Arg1)
```

is the type of a function taking two arguments, of types `Arg0` and `Arg1` and returning a result of type `Result`.